# iMessage (Mac): how to remove unrecoverable account?

Tags: macos, mac, user-accounts, instant-messaging

**What I want to archieve:**

- I want to remove a "dead" (old) account from iMessage, so it stops asking us to login with no longer known credentials - on every boot up of the workstation

**Circumstances:**

- The account password is not stored on the machine
- The password is not known anymore, I forgot it
- The account cannot be recovered in this case, please consider this as fact.
- The remove button [ - ] *(screenshot: bottom left)* in iMessage is disabled.
- (Thus it seems impossible to remove the account for me? Please help.)

*Operating System: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, update not possible, we sadly need to use 32bit software in our company that is no longer maintained nor updated. Apple does not care much and ditched support on it.*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried adding a 'correct' ID, I'm assuming you cannot remove the last remaining ID, so once there's a second one, the first may be deletable. [I can't test]. btw, why do you consider the original ID irrecoverable?

Comment: The supposedly correct credentials don't work and apple lets you wait ages and makes it as hard as possible to recover the account when you don't own an iPhone where you could instantly recover the account. We only got the wait option which I don't really consider as option because then something else won't work and we begin waiting from scratch and so on. (Already tried and failed to get in). I want it gone without much ado. Also I do not have an apple ID to add. We don't use Apple IDs (anymore). I can't say why.I don't see why I can't disable it. We don't even use iMessage.

Comment: I'd compare this to "fighting city hall" as the Americans would say. The OS itself & half the software on there is 'owned' by an AppleID. You will struggle, long-term, without one. if this is a company machine, then look at MDM solutions, one central company ID, many user-machines.

Comment: I'm totally with you there. It's just not that easy in the company I'm having the issue at, if you read between my lines. I hoped you could just disable a software that you don't need anyway.

Comment: Have you checked the solution found by the OP him/herself in this thread here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181742/how-do-i-remove-an-imessage-account-from-os-x-yosemite-messages-app)? OS versions are different, but as is often the case with macOS or OS X, closing the app and deleting associated .plist files works wonders... Worth a try. Make sure to open the .plist files before deletion, and check if you can edit them to remove the unwanted account from them first. You'd need Xcode installed to edit the files, I presume (that's how I do it).

Comment: It *did* work like a charm, no matter how many times I opened iMessage and CMD+Q - Closed it, however, after a reboot the whole crap begins from scratch. (meaning the problem still occurs) - eventhough the account does not appear within iMessage itself, it still explicitly asks for exactly that account. (A fresh reinstall of the OS would most likely work but that's totally insane and overkill IMO)

Comment: Some people advise to sign out and back in iCloud.

Comment: Thanks alot for your response, but also please keep in mind we're searching for an accountless solution at this point. The decision about that is out of my hands in this case unfortunately.

Comment: It seems like the [Movavi Mac Cleaner](https://www.movavi.com/mac-cleaner/) can remove iMessage itself, as described [here](https://www.movavi.com/support/how-to/mac/how-to-delete-imessage.html). It seems to be free.

Comment: Thanks, however scrolling down reveals the app actually costs 30 bucks and can only uninstall system apps prior to OSX 10.10, unfortunately. OP states 10.13.6 is in use.

Comment: It seems that if Apple can't help in the matter, is reinstallation an option?

Comment: That could possibly solve the problem regarding iMessage but it seems pretty much overkill.

Comment: More files to remove in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/172212) and this [article](https://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/an-idiots-guide-to-imessage.196827/).

Comment: Thanks alot, however all research and all suggestions unfortunately still lead to nowhere yet. Did everything the thread you link to suggested, still recieving this result. https://i.imgur.com/WgcUgpG.png - At least I did not recognize any negative side effects from trying and deleting (literally) "random" files.